# How to set up a loop that only scans N amount of times

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I'm a new beginner to programming, so please keep answers as simple to comprehend as possible, thanks!
In the program I'm attempting I need it to scan a different number (N) of strings depending on the number "N" a user inputs, and compare the strings to see if they are equal or not.

I thought I'd use a for loop but that doesn't seem to work.

```
printf("How many rows will there be?\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        scanf("%s", &string1[N]);
        scanf("%s", &string2[N]);
        result = strncmp(string1, string2, compareLimit);
```

is what I have now, but i want to repeat the "scanf("%s", &string1[N]);" line N times. Any advice?? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Place braces `{}` around the indented lines if you want them to all be part of your loop

Comment: You want to repeat in a loop, thats ok take input in for loop.But where will you store them..in the same string, this is C so first allocate memory for the strings where you will store them.

Comment: So you want to put the read string to i dex `j`? Then just do that, instead of using clnstant index `N`... :-). Also, add `{}`. Also, paste more complete code, with all variable definitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("How many rows will there be?\n");
scanf("%d", &N);
/* GET MEMORY FOR N STRING VARIABLES */

for (j = 0; j < N; j++)

    {
     scanf("%s", &string1[N]); /* TOOK INPUT N TIMES BUT ..ITS OVERWRITING ONLY */
     scanf("%s", &string2[N]);
    }
    result = strncmp(string1, string2, compareLimit); /*U WANT TO COMPARE AT EACH RUN OF                      LOOP THEN INCLUDE THIS ALSO,IT  RETURNS 0 IF SAME */
```

Your question/program is not clear, so its difficult to say what u want to know.